In Kibana dashboard, how do you transform a Field value that contains JSON (in fluentd Data View)?
Versions:
Elasticsearch / Kibana:  8.6.0
AWS EKS k8s:  1.24
k8s logging operator:  ghcr.io/banzaicloud/logging-operator:3.17.10

Our logging stack is Elasticsearch => fluentd => Kibana.
We use a fluentd Data View (our Index filter was fluentd* when we created the view).
We now see message and message.keyword fields in the fluentd Data View, where message is a JSON object containing service logs.  For example, the message field might look like this:
{
  "file": "/builds/foo/program-code.go:88",
  "func": "gitlab.com/foo/... evaluateExpression",
  "level": "debug",
  "msg": "cr1s81bpak3gl2qi2t50 : expression row.Email result is foo.bar@acme.com (error: <nil>)",
  "time": "2024-08-19T22:15:35.776968661Z"
}

QUESTION:  can we transform the message field so that what is rendered in our Data View is not this JSON object but instead the string contained in the JSON property message.msg?

To remove all fields except 'msg', you can utilize the record modifier plugin. This plugin assists in altering fields within the records. Below is an example of how you can apply it:
<filter pattern>
  @type record_modifier

  whitelist_keys msg
</filter>

Complete documentation is available for consultation at the following sources: https://github.com/repeatedly/fluent-plugin-record-modifier
